# Porcentaje con join MSYQL

Tags: mysql

Como podria presentar la informacion en porcentaje?
La idea es que presente el porcentaje que esta siendo utilizado del hotel, vaya que tan lleno esta el hotel, y todo sale bien ,solo necesito saber como presentar los datos en porcentaje, aqui el query:

```
    SELECT ROUND(COUNT(EST.IdEstatusHabitacion)*100/COUNT(HAB.IdHabitacion)) Porcentaje Lleno 
      FROM HABITACION HAB 
 LEFT JOIN (SELECT IdEstatusHabitacion FROM ESTATUSHABITACION WHERE IdEstatusHabitacion=2) EST ON HAB.IdEstatusHabitacion=EST.IdEstatusHabitacion;
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el probelma que tienes con esto?

Answer (score -2):

```
Select CONCAT(ROUND(COUNT(EST.IdEstatusHabitacion)*100/COUNT(HAB.IdHabitacion)), ' %') As Total From estadisticas;
```

ó algo así...

Comment: En general, las respuestas que tienen solo código, son consideradas de baja calidad. Sugiero que leas [answer] y que agregues una breve explicación de cómo tu código resuelve el problema planteado en la pregunta. Un saludo.